# Problems using Scala set collection from Java

Tags: java, scala, collections

There is actually another question on this subject:

[example of using scala.collection.immutable.Set from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025291/example-of-using-scala-collection-immutable-set-from-java)

But the information seems to no longer be correct.

I'm trying to work with immutable Scala sets:

```
class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    scala.collection.Set<Integer> mySet = 
      new scala.collection.immutable.Set.Set1<Integer>(1);
    mySet = mySet.$plus(3);
  } 
}
```

However, at runtime this fails:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.Set.$plus(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/SetLike;
    at Foo.main(Foo.java:4)
```

The previous discussion on StackOverflow implies that the solution to this problem is to use the Addable trait.  However, it was removed a few versions back.  There is actually a StackOverlow discussion of that as well

[Why is Scala's Addable deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392966/why-is-scalas-addable-deprecated)

However, the advice there to use +: or :+ doesn't help me as Sets being unordered do not have those methods.

There is a SetLike trait available, but it only changes the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.SetLike.$plus(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/SetLike;
at Foo.main(Foo.java:4)
```

Just in case it matters:

```
% scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

% java -version   
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I managed to avoid relying on the undocumented, private internal `SetN` classes by using `scala.collection.Set<String> mySet = scala.collection.Set$.MODULE$.empty();` to construct an empty set, but since I otherwise get the same error as you, the satisfaction is rather academic at this point. Interestingly, `toString()` seems to work, I can print out the empty set just fine.

Comment: The use of the undocumented SetN class was something was just trying when adding directly to the empty set via $plus wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GenSet seems to be the trait you were looking for:

```
class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    scala.collection.GenSet<Integer> mySet =
      scala.collection.Set$.MODULE$.<Integer>empty();
    mySet = mySet.$plus(3);
  }
}
```

or

```
class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    scala.collection.GenSet<Integer> mySet =
            new scala.collection.immutable.Set.Set1<Integer>(1);
    mySet = mySet.$plus(3);
  }
}
```

Comment: That resolves the problem, thanks!  It is a little less than ideal, as it does mean some additional casting back and forth between scala.collection.Set<T> and scala.collection.GenSet<T>, but it is manageable.

Comment: The strange thing is that `GenSet` is a supertype of `Set`, so it should have *less* methods, not more.